# derivative of ln inside ln

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=ln(ln2x^4)$

To find the derivative of this would I have to find the derivative of the inside and then do the derivative of the entire ln function on the inside? Such as the derivative of the inside is $\frac{4}{x}$ and the derivative of the outer ln is $\frac{1}{ln2x^4}$. Then I multiply the two together to get the final answer of $\frac{4}{xln2x^4}$?

Answer (score 1):

By the Chain Rule:

$$\left(\log\log(2x^4)\right)'=\frac1{\log2x^4}\frac1{2x^4}8x^3$$

and now do some algebraic order in the above.